# Fix yellowish Dell G15 display color on Pop OS/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, display, colors

I have two laptops being one old of mine called Sony VAIO SVE series and another one that I bought it recently that is a Dell G15 with Intel i7 Processor and nVIDIA GeForce RTX video card where I am using two OS's (Pop OS and Windows 11 by default), but I noticed compared with my another old laptop (Sony VAIO) that the display is much yellowish causing some discomforting to my eyes.

I saw that there are calibration devices that could be attached on the screen but they are expensive and I have tried to call to the Dell tech support, he adviced to update the video card driver to calibrate the colors on Windows 11 but nothing happened.

Is there any tip to adjust the screen colors and fix the yellowish through Pop OS/Ubuntu without need to use Windows?

Comment: There is color calibration in Windows.  If you start in Windows does the Windows calibration help you?

Comment: If I calibrate the colors on Windows does it make any effect on Pop OS also? I am gonna do a dig to know how to calibrate the colors on Windows 11!

Comment: If the Windows calibration works, you can run Pop OS in a virtual machine as the Windows display calibration affects the screen even in the VM

Comment: I am running Pop OS on dual boot

Comment: Yes I know but virtual machines work so much better

Comment: Yeah, or if I use Pop OS as a primary system and Windows in virtual machine? It's because I use more linux systems to programming/development

Comment: If you have a fast SSD drive, virtual machines are also fast . I mention this as you are trying to reduce color intensity which is primarily a Windows function